# Video streaming from Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, ffserver

I want to live stream video from android device. I found out that ffserver (ffmpeg) can be compiled and run on android. Now i need to get video from camera in android device and get it to the ffserver in real-time.

Any ideas?

Regards,
MM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would look at [android.hardware.Camera](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) and [android.media.MediaRecorder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html). You set the "camera" for the media recorder and it has a start/stop methods. It streams the output to a file when you start it, and closes the file when you stop.

[This](http://marakana.com/forums/android/android_examples/39.html) may be another good reference to look at.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already look at Camera and MediaRecorder, but with MediaRecorder I can save video into mp4 or 3gpp format, this formats may cause problems to real-time streaming. If I'll not found other solution, I will try with this. 

Currenty I'm looking for how to send video from camera directly to ffserver without MediaRecorders encoding. 

regards,

Comment: hmmm, would android.hardware.Camera work with an external USB webcam and a slate PC running Android, do you know?